# What is the correct way to modify an ndarray in Python (numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm finding that modifying/assigning a numpy.ndarray like: 
    X[j,...,c] = something. 
is not working the way I would expect. Please see the following code snippet and the accompanying output

```
X_train_norm = np.zeros_like(X_train)
for j in range(100, 102):
   for c in range(X_train.shape[-1]):
      X_train_norm[j,...,c] = X_train[j,...,c] - means[j, c]
      print(j, c, np.mean(X_train_norm[j,...,c]), np.mean(X_train[j,...,c] - means[j,c]))


100 0 152.491210938 0.0
100 1 153.384765625 0.0
100 2 164.598632812 0.0
101 0 148.837890625 0.0
101 1 151.559570312 0.0
101 2 162.604492188 0.0

(means is a Nx3 array and X_train is a Nx32x32x3 array)
```

What is the right way to create the output?

EDIT: I got it working with a code snippet like this:

```
z = X_train[j,...] - means[j,]
if X_train_norm is None:
    X_train_norm = np.array(z, ndmin=4)
else:
    X_train_norm = np.vstack([X_train_norm, np.array(z, ndmin=4)])
```

I am sure there is a more efficient and pythonic way to do this. Thanks for looking!

Comment: `"is not working the way I would expect`" Elaborate?

Comment: If I compute `z = X_train[j,...,c] - means[j, c]`, z looks very different than if I  do `X_train_norm[j,...,c] = ....`. The output illustrates that.

Comment: Updated snippet with code that works

Answer (score 0):

Duh! It was a type issue.

```
X_train was uint8.
X_train_norm = np.zeros_like(X_train,dtype='float64')
X_train_norm = X_train_norm.astype(float)
for j in range(100, 102):
   z = X_train[j,...] - means[j,]
   print(z.shape, z.mean())
   X_train_norm[j] = z
   print(X_train_norm[j].shape, X_train_norm[j].mean())
```

correctly prints

```
(32, 32, 3) 0.0
(32, 32, 3) 0.0
(32, 32, 3) 0.0
(32, 32, 3) 0.0
```